# Order and limit data based on JSONB array

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have such a PostgreSQL table

```
id   data(jsonb)
--   ------------------------------------
23   {"val": [30, 5, 1]}
41   {"val": [11, 4, 99]}
99   {"val": [2]}
```

Now I would like to get all sorted val and have the limitation for each query (for pagination).
For example
1st query

```
val
-----
1
2
4
5
11
```

2nd query

```
val
-----
30
99
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unnest the array, sort the result then apply offset and limit:

```
select v.value::int
from the_table t
  cross join jsonb_array_elements_text(t.data -> 'val') as v(value)
order by v.value::int
offset 0 --<< start of page
limit 5 --<< page size
;
```

Instead of `limit 5` you can also use the standard compliant `fetch first 5 rows only`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `cte` to transform the JSON data and then apply the pagination logic in the main query:

```
with results(id, v) as ( 
    select row_number() over (order by v.value::int), v.value::int from tbl t 
    cross join jsonb_array_elements(t.data -> 'val') v
)
select r.v from results r where 5*(<query_num> - 1) < r.id and r.id <= 5*(<query_num> - 1) + 5
```